# Exception in SSL with GET Request using Authorize Bearer header with Kimono Labs

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, http-get

I'm developing a mobile app that involves parsing data from JSON object via Kimono Labs. I am having problem when it comes to SSL and certificates when accessing the APIs at Kimono Labs.

According to Kimono Labs, calling the API requires setting the header "Authorization: Bearer " header at the call.

> GET Request 
>   Calling an auth API using a GET request is just like calling any kimono api, but you will additionally need to pass your secure token in the Authentication request header, like so: Authorization: Bearer {YOUR_SECURE_TOKEN}

I'm using the following code to get InputStream

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(apiURL);
request.addHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + securityToken);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
InputStream is = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
```

Executing this code gives me an exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Alternatively I tried implementing with the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(apiURL);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + securityToken);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");     urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.internet_timeout)); urlConnection.setReadTimeout(activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.internet_timeout));
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

With this code I am having the exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Any ideas?

I am able to "hack" solve it by allowing all certificates via CustomTrustManager and CustomAllVerifier returning true for all attempts but heard this is totally unsafe and is not recommended for production. Is this true in my case?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem with a node.js build using kimono as api. The problem is that the intermediate signed cert is not trusted by Mozilla, ergo nodejs throws a leaf error.

I solved it by doing the following, find which cert is being used, download the pem for it and add it to your root CA's before doing the request to kimono, its a hell of a lot safer than disabling TLS/SSL security checks.

Comment: I'll give that a heads up! Thank you for this suggestion. I'll let you know how it goes. Somewhat new to SSL and CA.

Comment: after inspecting the code, I noticed that I can simply accept all requests if it's from hostname of kimonolabs.com. Do you think this is also a viable solution?
    public class KimonoVerifier implements HostnameVerifier {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        if(hostname.equals("www.kimonolabs.com"){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up! Turned out that this is a temporary problem with kimonolabs' server.